# timer in iOS not working 

Tags: ios, nstimer

I have this code for a repeated timer in my app:

(inside viewDidAppear)

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow: 3];
NSTimer *restrictionTimer = [[NSTimer alloc] initWithFireDate: date
                                      interval: 3
                                        target: self
                                      selector:@selector(changeRestriction)
                                      userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

and

```
- (void) changeRestriction
{
    NSLog(@"inside !!");
}
```

However, I dont see any output, any help ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using `-initWithFireDate:..` you have to manually add the timer to the NSRunLoop. However you could just use `+scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:..` and it will automatically trigger.